# New Western Digital Black HD not being detected by Windows

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, bios, computer-building

I added a new HD to my PC, but it isn't being detected by Windows 8.

I've checked the cables and it does appear in the BIOS. It isn't listed in the Disk Management in Windows, though.

I don't think it would be dead, since it's new, and it appears in the BIOS.

Comment: If you boot from a linux liveCD, does it work in there? Perhaps you could use that to format it NTFS.

Comment: @Xyon I don't have one.

Comment: Not yet perhaps, but if you have a blank CD you can download one and burn it. Or even a USB drive is possible.

Comment: Is it working on Windows 7?

Comment: @avirk I don't have Windows 7.

Comment: @user912 then its better to check it out someone's PC who has Windows 7 and check if it works. Then it will be clear that this is the only issue with Windows 8 and not dead.

Comment: @Xyon I just checked on linux, and it doesn't appear.

Comment: Does sound like it's struggling for something then. Despite it functioning at a low level for BIOS, it doesn't seem like it's starting up properly. Have you checked in your BIOS setup that the settings for it are correct?

Comment: @Xyon What do you mean by checking the settings?

Comment: Enter BIOS setup (usually F2 or DEL while the POST is running) and check out how your drive is listed and set up in there. There are probably a few options which could cause it to not start up, or not be accessible in a way the OS expects.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how, but after leaving it off for a night, the hard drive was detected, and I've successfully formatted it.

I wish I knew how, but I don't.

Comment: Magic in yer POST.